# One problem from Graph Theory.

Tags: graph-theory

**Suppose that the vertex set of a graph G is a (finite) set of integers. Two vertices x and y are
adjacent if x + y is odd. To which well-known class of graphs is G a member?**

Comment: It's a bipartite graph. Two numbers are connected if and only if one is odd and the other is even.

Comment: Thank you sir.. Sir Can you please draw the graph??

Comment: I cannot draw the graph without knowing the set of vertices.

Comment: Then what will be it's answer??

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's bipartite. odd numbers connect to evens but not to other odds, and vice versa. Take the integers 1 to 10 and draw the connections.

Comment: Thank you sir.. Sir Can you please draw the graph??

Comment: Not sir -- Victoria is a woman's name just FYI.

I suggest you draw the graph yourself. Start with the numbers 1 to 10. 1 connects with 2,4,6,8, 10 but NOT with 3,5,7,9. 2 connects with 1,3,5,7,9, but NOT with 4,6,8,10, and so on.

Comment: Sorry Mam.. And thank you for your suggestion..

Comment: Even more: it is complete bipartite.